# SQL create separate columns based on values of an existing column

Tags: sql, preset

I have a table looking like this with the following query in SQL

```
SELECT UpdateDate as DATE , 
Username ,
Request as Type ,
AmountUSD as Amount 
FROM tgm.tr_active 
where Request in ('Successfull','Declined');
```

[image]

And i would like to run a query and get the following results creating separate columns for eache type with the appropriate values , otherwise the value will be 0 like this :

[image]

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please Google for "MySQL pivot query" or have a read of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql).

Comment: add the tag reflecting what db you are using!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following query for your expected output.

```
SELECT UpdateDate AS DATE,
       Username,
       CASE
           WHEN TYPE='Successfull' THEN Amount
           ELSE 0
       END AS 'Successfull',
       CASE
           WHEN TYPE='Declined' THEN Amount
           ELSE 0
       END AS 'Declined'
FROM tr_active
WHERE Request in ('Successfull',
                  'Declined');
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Sorry for the late response , this actually helped thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Use `IF`

```
SELECT
  Date,
  Username,
  IF (Type = 'Successful', Amount, 0) AS Successful,
  IF (Type = 'Declined', Amount, 0) AS Declined 
FROM table_1
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response , this actually helped thank you very much